# How do I save the last graphical output of Animate so as to make it the background for the next Animate?

Tags: graphics, animation, output

I am making an instructional program in which a random number appears and moves across and down into the appropriate bin, landing on top of the existing stack. Then another number appears, repeating the animation sequence until it lands on top of its own stack.  When any stack reaches the top, the animation stops and this example of the distribution can be observed.

Thus,I wish to combine a sequence of animations, using the output of one to serve as the background to the next.  How can I save the final graph of each `Animate` sequence so as to use it for the input of the next?  The fact that animations are  examples of `Manipulate` complicates matters.  `Do` loops, etc. do not work here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is actually what you want, but I think this might be an approach:

```
Manipulate[temp = {Green, Disk[{5, 0}, {3, 1}]};
Animate[
plot = Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}, Prolog -> temp], {a, 0, 5}, 
AnimationRunning -> True], 
Button["Snapshot", 
temp = {Texture[Rasterize[plot]], 
Polygon[{Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}], 
Scaled[{0, 1}]}, 
VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]]
```

[image]